# Transforming large dataset into reduced object

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a very fast growing rethink DB and I need to create some aggregation queries to lessen the load on the clients. Here is an example document list:

```
[
    {
        created_ts: 1424389239198,
        cost: 2,
        id: '12345678'
    },
    {
        created_ts: 1424389239198,
        cost: 2,
        id: '12345678'
    },
    {
        created_ts: 1424389239198,
        cost: 2,
        id: '12345678'
    }
]
```

What I ultimately want is an aggregation of cost based on the hour the data was created(created_ts is stored as epoch time). To get the hour from created_ts I can do:

```
r.epochTime(row('created_ts')).hours()
```

I need data, grouped by hours in a day that looks similiar to this:

```
[
    {
        hour: 0,
        total_cost: 6
    },
    {
        hour: 1,
        total_cost: 10
    },
    {
        hour: 2,
        total_cost: 24
    }
]
```

That data says at hour "0" (midnight) I had a total cost of 6, at 1 AM the total cost was 10, etc. I have only gotten it so that it's grouped by hour but I can't seem to get it into a "pretty" object like the one above. Any help is much appreciated. Examples in JavaScript are much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your answer as grouped data like so:

```
r.table('test').group(function(row) {
  return r.epochTime(row('created_ts')).hours();
}).sum('cost')
```

If you want the exact format you specified, you can do it like this:

```
r.table('test').group(function(row) {
  return r.epochTime(row('created_ts')).hours();
}).sum('cost').ungroup().map(function(gr) {
  return {hour: gr('group'), cost: gr('reduction')}
})
```

Comment: (Thanks mlucy and AtnNn) That should work, but I think I may still have a problem. In the future, this query could be working with millions of rows. The goup() method is limited to about 100,000 rows right?

Comment: Oh and as a follow up, THANK YOU! This did work like a charm. The only open question I have is how well this will scale with potentially millions of rows. Any insight on that would be great if you have experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group` on your table, `sum` the costs and then `map` over the results to get the structure you want:

```
r.table('foo')
 .group(r.epochTime(r.row('created_ts').div(1000)).hours())
 .sum('cost')
 .ungroup()
 .map({hour: r.row('group'), total_cost: r.row('reduction')})
```